# List of boost::Unique_Ptr objects

Tags: c++, boost, unique-ptr

Why can I not do this?

```
typedef boost::interprocess::unique_ptr<QueueList, QueueListDeletor> UQList;
typedef boost::intrusive::list<UQList> List;  // Compiler (VS 2003) complains
```

The QueueList is a class that derives from  `public boost::intrusive::list_base_hook<>` to make it part of an intrusive linked list.

I want to use unique_ptr to be able to pass around this object between threads and only have 1 single thread have ownership of this object at the time.

EDIT:
ERRORS:

error C2039: 'pointer' : is not a member of 'boost::intrusive::detail::default_list_hook'
        see declaration of 'boost::intrusive::detail::default_list_hook'
        see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::intrusive::list_impl' being compiled
        with
        [
            Config=boost::intrusive::listopt::value_traits,boost::intrusive::size_type::pack>::type,boost::intrusive::constant_time_size>::type>::size_type,true>
        ]

error C2039: 'const_pointer' : is not a member of 'boost::intrusive::detail::default_list_hook'
        see declaration of 'boost::intrusive::detail::default_list_hook'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QueueList may be derived from list_base_hook, but UQList certainly isn't. Since you try to create an intrusive list of UQList (which is a unique_ptr) and not an intrusive list of QueueList objects, this won't work.